# how to reset etsa function GetJoystickNames in unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript

the problem is that if I connect a command the array
GetJoystickNames increases an index but if you disconnect it does not reduce the index and continues counting as if it were connected

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using? I presume you're actually writing C#, not the deprecated language UnityScript as specified in the question tags you've chosen?

Answer (score 2):

You don't. As per the [GetJoystickNames documentation (version 2019.1)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetJoystickNames.html):

> Note that some entries in the array may be blank if no device is
>   connected for that joystick number.

As such, the length of the array is not intended to correspond to the number of connect joysticks.